How to pass array by reference from Javascript to C++ via WebIDL & WebIDL binder?
What's the idioamtic way to define a function that takes an array as an argument in WebIDL such that WebIDL binder generates Javascript bindings that are "pass by reference"?
So I could do something like this:
void Foo::process_array(float array[], int num_frames)
{    
  for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++) {
    array[i] *= 0.5;
  }  
}

and call it like this in js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
foo.process_array(arr, arr.length)
console.debug(arr)
// > [0.5, 1., 1.5]


One way to pass arrays using WebIDL is this:
interface.idl:
interface Foo {
  void Foo();
  void process_array(sequence<float> foo, long num_frames);
};

main.hpp:
struct Foo {
  Foo();
  void process_array(float foo[], int num_frames);
};

If calling the generated wrapper code like this, in accordance to the docs, the array gets passed by value - the array gets copied in, but not copied out, of the heap.
Then there's frozen arrays that appear to do what I like, but they can only be used as attributes of objects, not parameters.
I could just copy the output buffer to an attribute, but then I have to

wrap the C++ method in an object just to keep the output buffer
wrap the js method to get back the behaviour I'd like to have:

const arr = [1, 2, 3]
foo.process_array(arr, arr.length)
arr = [...foo.output]
console.debug(arr)


are you sure, that param float array[], is correct. I believe, it must me double.

BTW, float array[] is not passing array by reference, as it is equivalent to float* array.

JavaScript will never pass an entire array by value into a function call of any type, unless the function call is explicitly written to spread an array parameter into an argument list.

@Pointy I know, it's more a wrapper js question.

@Jarod42 shouldn't matter, or does it? I just want the array modified in place.

Thou Shalt Not Modify JS Object From C++ Code!
Emscripten provides a linear Memory object which you can allocate on; this works like C++ malloc, so you get a pointer to a buffer that can hold your requested number of bytes and you can pass that pointer directly to C++. Then you need to free it after you're done using it. You also need to watch out for the size of this Memory object, either fixing a maximum size or enable memory growth.
You can copy data to your buffer using HEAP*.set or use it as described in this answer. Simple linear memory copy is fast but your data needs to be copyable, e.g. an ImageData object; in your case you can use a suitable typed array. See Emscripten documentation for more details, they're kinda scattered.
If you don't use this approach, all your JS objects aren't passed directly, but used to construct specified C++ types. Emscripten provides bindings for basic types, e.g. it's able to write an ArrayBuffer to std::string, and you can write your own bindings for any more complex types you need, e.g. JS array into std::vector. However, this often includes copy-processing data in more complex ways, which is why it's slow and not recommended for large data. This is what's happening to you and the problem you're running into - you'll always be passing values, the only thing you can change is passing a pointer by value instead of a whole non-trivial object.

If that's the only way to do it, that seems like a great shortcoming of webidl. I'm using it precisely so I don't have to allocate/free memory myself

It's a limitation of Emscripten/WASM themselves. Makes sense when you consider the kind of security risks that could result from allowing sneaky scripts to modify memory, among other stuff.

@Nearoo If performance isn't a concern, just use pass-by-value and return value, it's more transparent than in-place modification anyway. If it is a concern, you'll have to get used to managing where, when and how your data is stored as it can affect performance a lot.

I don't understand how it makes a difference i.t.o. performance? Whether I manually allocate an input array, then copy it back before using, or use the wrapper code that copies it back for me shouldn't matter, no? I would expect the wrapper to allow me to write code such that the allocated memory buffer is copied back into the js array for me. I don't expect the wasm to modify the js heap directly, I highly doubt that's even possible.

@Nearoo The wrapper code doesn't necessarily perform a trivial copy (e.g. calling memcpy). JS doesn't approach types the same way as C/C++, so proper type conversions are necessary in the general case. (Imagine you're storing int16 as float.) You should be able to write your own wrappers that convert more efficiently, it just won't give you the option to modify in place. Note that converting to/from std::vector is still a type of allocation handling, just one that offloads most work to std::vector and RAII; there's no difference in principle from malloc calls, only level of detail.

@Nearoo Check out Emscripten documentation, specifically helper functions like convertJSArrayToNumberVector and what sort of checks it doesn't do. It's also possible (depending on how complicated operations you want to actually perform on your data inside JS code) that conversion won't be a performance bottleneck for you, I'm just saying you need to keep in mind that it looks automatic, but there's a lot going on under the hood.

@Nearoo I should also mention that the method I describe requires you to send an address on the WASM module's Memory (heap) object to allow in-place modification, but you can use the modified data in JS directly as a TypedArray view. The WASM function doesn't care how the data got to input address or how it's used after modification, it only modifies in-place as far as the WASM module is concerned. No data conversion or even looking at the data in underlying buffer is performed, since the input is only the address of the buffer. This is the fastest option.

You're making it way more complicated than it needs to be. You're also not solving my problem. The only thing I hear out of your answer is: it's not possible to copy back the array automatically using the wrapper code. But your answer starts with "Thou Shalt Not Modify JS Object From C++ Code!"; this is unrelated to my question, and also impossible unless you introduce more wrapper code. I think you're also not entirely aware that it's literally impossible to access the JS's underlying linear memory rom WASM. Everything happens through wrapper.

@Nearoo I guess you just don't understand what pass by reference means. It's in place modification of the object whose address you pass to the function, not some syntax for in&out wrapper for the underlying object. All function arguments are input only, always, but when the argument is an address, you can modify the data at that address (value). You can't coerce C++ to call some wrapper code for an argument automatically on return. Only your return values are converted through wrapper code back to JS objects.

"and also impossible unless you introduce more wrapper code" - In that sentence, I'm telling you it's impossible always, no matter what wrapper code. All you can do with wrapper is make a copy of the object you're passing (e.g. an address on Memory object) to a C++ type (e.g. pointer), modify that, and then wrap the return value into a new object that you can use in JS e.g. to reassign. The object you passed is unaffected in C++ code. I'm also telling you that you can only modify the data on WASM linear memory object from WASM and not any other JS memory.

If you already knew how the JS memory model works, it would've been useful to mention that in your question and that you don't want to deal with it on JS side, since using pass by reference in WASM is a common beginner idea. So you want to strictly stick to wrapper code and do all memory handling in there? You'll need to use return values then.
